# Reference for: projecting a knot on a generic plane yields a smooth oriented curve intersecting itself transversly at finitely many double points

Tags: reference-request, knot-theory

I need a reference for the following statement: Given a smooth link $L \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, for a generic choice of a plane $P\subset \mathbb{R^3}$, the projection of the link $L$ on it is a smooth oriented immersed curve with finitely many double points where two strands intersect transversly.

I have read this statement in the book "Grid Homology for Knots and Links" by Peter S. Ozsvath, Andras I. Stipsicz, and Zoltan Szabo on page 14 but with no reference. Then there is a similar statement for PL-knots in "Knots" by Gerhard Burde and Heiner Zieschang on page 9, but I want it for smooth links. I also did not find anything in "Introduction to Knot Theory" by Lickorish and other classic books. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I haven't thought about this in detail lately, but I think it is just a consequence of basic differential topology.  The intersections of the image will be stable (reaching back into my memories... ) which means if you wiggle the plane or the knot, the intersection's tangent spaces look the same.  I.e. you won't pick up or loose any crossings.  If you did, then you happened to pick a bad projection plane.  But these are unlikely in the sense that will happen with probability 0.  Almost-every projection plane does what you want it to.  Now if I could find a reference... Guilleman and Pollack?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I could not find such a statement in Guilleman and Pollack.

Comment: Right, you won't find it explicitly stated.  You want to look at statements about stability and transversality.  Then I think you can piece it together.

Comment: @N. Owad Is the following argument pieced together correctly? Any of the listed conditions on the plane $P$ are actually stable (i.e. preserved by small perturbations) by the stability theorem in Guilleman Pollack, page 35. Now one can show that the planes which do not satisfy all conditions, have measure 0 by  Sard's theorem. Therefore a plane satisfying these conditions is generic.

Comment: Yes, that is sounding like exactly what you want. Nice.  You should write it up and post it here once you have the details worked out.

Comment: Is this what you want? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271402/regular-projection-of-a-link-proof-in-the-smooth-category